# Perl cgi not passing the hash to mysql

Tags: mysql, perl

I have an assignment which requires us to create a quiz form in perl cgi accepting new questions from our local web browser. Each insertion of question need to be updated in state table, and at the end should display number of questions exists in database as well as new questions inserted at each session.I used HTML for forms and Mysql as my database and running on localhost. When I try to add a new quesion the only thing that makes it into the table is the Question, nothing else gets added.  I can see the values in the URL being passed to the seerver but the data never makes it to the SQL statment.   Please help.

```
#! /usr/bin/perl
#use strict;
#use warnings;
#use diagnostics;
print "Content-type: text/html\n\n";

if ($ENV{"REQUEST_METHOD"} eq "POST") {
  read(STDIN, $datastring, $ENV{"CONTENT_LENGTH"});     
}
elsif (exists $ENV{"REQUEST_METHOD"}) {     # data from GET transaction (or HEAD or other)
  $datastring = $ENV{"QUERY_STRING"};
}
else {
  print "Offline execution detected\n";
  print "Please enter some data.\n";
  $datastring = <>;
  chomp $datastring;
  print "== data accepted == HTML output follows ==\n\n";
}

###decode######################################################
$datastring =~s/%0D%0A/\n/g;                        #step to deal with line
                                                    #breaks in text areas
@nameValuePairs = split(/&/, $datastring);          #step 1
foreach $pair (@nameValuePairs) {
  ($name, $value) = split(/=/, $pair);              #step 2
  $name =~tr/+/ /;                                  #step 3
  $name =~s/%([\da-fA-F]{2})/pack("C",hex($1))/eg;  #step 3
  $value =~tr/+/ /;                                 #step 3
  $value =~s/%([\da-fA-F]{2})/pack("C",hex($1))/eg; #step 3

  if(exists $formHash{$name}) {                     #improved step 4,
    $formHash{$name} = $formHash{$name}.";".$value; #now handles multiple
  }                                                 #select menus
  else {
    $formHash{$name} = $value;
  }
}
###done decoding###############################################

### global variables ##########################################
use DBI;
$dbhandle = DBI->connect("DBI:mysql:databasexx", "idyy", "passzz")  
    or &errorPage("Can't connect to database". DBI->errstr()); 
$file_life_span = 1.0/24; # in days (so is 1 hours)
$time_out = 1.0/24;
$time_out = 1.0/24; # in days
$cache_limit = 300;
$state_table_name = "stable";  # name of state table
$quiz_table_name = "qtable";     # name of quiz table
%stateHash=();
### end of global variables #####################################

### app logic ###################################################
if($formHash{"request"} eq "menu") {
    &menu;
}
elsif($formHash{"request"} eq "add") {
    &add;
}
elsif($formHash{"request"} eq "add2") {
    &add2;
}
elsif($formHash{"request"} eq "list") {
    &list;
}
else {
    &welcome;
}
### end app logic ################################################

##################################################################
sub welcome{
 my $sessionID = &get_long_id_db($dbhandle, $state_table_name, $cache_limit, $file_life_span);
 $qnumber=1;
 %stateHash = ("qnumber"=>$qnumber);
 &write_state_db($dbhandle, $state_table_name, $sessionID, %stateHash);

 print <<PAGE;
 <html><head><title>Welcome</title></head>
  <body>
   <h2>Welcome</h2>
    <form action="$ENV{SCRIPT_NAME}" method="GET">
     <input type="hidden" name="qnumber" value="$qnumber">
     <input type="hidden" name="id" value="$sessionID"/>
     <input type="hidden" name="request" value="menu">
     <input type="submit" value="Main Menu">
    </form>
 </body>
</html>
PAGE
}

##################################################################
sub menu{
  my $sessionID = $formHash{"id"};
  my $qnumber = $fromHash{"qnumber"};
print <<PAGE;
 <html><head><title>Menu</title></head>
  <body>
   <form action="$ENV{SCRIPT_NAME}" method="GET">
    <input type="hidden" name="qnumber" value="$qnumber"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="id" value="$sessionID"/>
    List the questions.<br>
    <button type="submit" name="request" value="list">List Questions</button>
    <br><br>
    Add a question.<br>
    <button type="submit" name="request" value="add">Add Question</button>
    <br><br>
  </form>
 </body>
</html>
PAGE
}

##################################################################
sub add{
  my $sessionID = $formHash{"id"};
  my $qnumber = $fromHash{"qnumber"};
  $sql = "SELECT * from $quiz_table_name";
  $qObj = $dbhandle -> prepare($sql);
  $qObj -> execute() or &errorPage("Can't execute " . $qObj->errstr());
  $qObj -> fetchall_arrayref(); # Fetch all rows, no need to use them
  my $number_of_questions = $qObj->rows();
  $qObj -> finish();

print <<PAGE;
 <html><head><title>Add Question</title></head>
  <body>
   There are $number_of_questions in the database now.<br>
   This will be your $qnumber question this session.
   <form action="$ENV{SCRIPT_NAME}" method="GET">
    <input type="hidden" name="qnumber" value="$qnumber"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="id" value="$sessionID"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="request" value="add2">
    <br/> 
    Enter the Question.<br>
    <INPUT TYPE="text" NAME="question" VALUE="Question"><br>
    Correct Answer.<br>
    <INPUT TYPE="text" NAME="answer" VALUE="Answer"><br>
    Choce #1.<br>
    <INPUT TYPE="text" NAME="choice1" VALUE="1"><br>
    Choce #2.<br>
    <INPUT TYPE="text" NAME="choice2" VALUE="2"><br>
    Choce #3.<br>
    <INPUT TYPE="text" NAME="choice3" VALUE="3"><br>
    Choce #4.<br>
    <INPUT TYPE="text" NAME="choice4" VALUE="4"><br>
    Choce #5.<br>
    <INPUT TYPE="text" NAME="choice5" VALUE="5"><br>
    <br/>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
  </form>   
 </body>
</html>
PAGE
}

##################################################################
sub add2{
  my $sessionID = $formHash{"id"};
  my $qnumber = $fromHash{"qnumber"};
  my $question = $formHash{"question"};
  my $answer = $fromHash{"answer"};
  my $choice1 = $fromHash{"choice1"};
  my $choice2 = $fromHash{"choice2"};
  my $choice3 = $fromHash{"choice3"};
  my $choice4 = $fromHash{"choice4"};
  my $choice5 = $fromHash{"choice5"};
   $stateHash{"qnumber"}++; # The next question number.
   &write_state_db($dbhandle, $state_table_name, $sessionID, %stateHash);
    $sql = "INSERT INTO $quiz_table_name(question, answer, choice1, choice2, choice3, choice4, choice5) VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
    $qObj = $dbhandle -> prepare($sql) or &errorPage("Can't prepare");
    $qObj -> execute($question, $answer, $choice1, $choice2, $choice3, $choice4, $choice5) or &errorPage("Can't execute " . $qObj->errstr());
    $qObj -> finish();
    $request = menu;
}

##################################################################
sub list {
  my $sessionID = $formHash{"id"};
  my $qnumber = $fromHash{"qnumber"};
 print <<PAGE; 
  <html><head><title>List Questions</title></head>
  <body>
   <h2>List Questions</h2><br/>

  <style>
    table, th, td {
    border: 1px solid black;
    }
    th {
    text-align: left;
    }
    </style>
    <table>
     <tr><th>Number</th><th>Question</th><th>Answer</th><th>Choice 1</th><th>Choice 2</th><th>Choice 3</th><th>Choice 4</th><th>Choice 5</th></tr>
PAGE
    # DEFINE A MySQL QUERY
     $sql = "SELECT qnumber, question, answer, choice1, choice2, choice3, choice4, choice5 FROM $quiz_table_name";
     $qObj = $dbhandle -> prepare($sql) or &errorPage("Can't prepare");
     $qObj -> execute() or &errorPage("Can't execute " . $qObj->errstr());
     my $arry_ref = $qObj->fetchall_arrayref();
     $qObj -> finish();
     foreach my $row(@$arry_ref)
     {
        my ($qnumber, $question, $answer, $choice1, $choice2, $choice3, $choice4, $choice5) = @$row;
        print "<tr><th>$qnumber</th><th>$question</th><th>$answer</th><th>$choice1</th><th>$choice2</th><th>$choice3</th><th>$choice4</th><th>$choice5</th></tr>";
     }
    # PRINT THE RESULTS
    print <<BOTTOM;
    </table>

 </body>
</html>
 <form action="$ENV{SCRIPT_NAME}" method="POST">
 <input type="hidden" name="qnumber" value="$qnumber"/>
 <input type="hidden" name="id" value="$sessionID"/>
 <input type="hidden" name="request" value="menu">
 <input type="submit" value="Main Menu">
     </form>
 </body>
</html>
BOTTOM
}


#################################################################
#################################################################
# end app logic functions
# begin toolkit functions
#################################################################
#################################################################

#################################################################
sub write_state_db {
  my ($dbhandle, $table_name, $sessionID, %states) = @_;
  ### add the updated last-modified time to the front of the incoming state hash
  my $currtime = time;
  my @updates = ("last_modified = '$currtime'");
  foreach $key (keys %states){
    push @updates, "$key = '$states{$key}'";
  }

  ###  update the state record
  $sql = "UPDATE $table_name set " . join(",", @updates) . " WHERE id = '$sessionID'";
  $qObj = $dbhandle -> prepare($sql);
  $qObj -> execute() or &errorPage("Can't execute " . $qObj->errstr());
  $qObj -> finish();
}

#################################################################
sub read_state_db {
  my ($dbhandle, $table_name, $sessionID, $time_out, 
        $time_out_function, $time_out_message) = @_;   ### $time_out is in days

  ### read the desired state record into the query object
  $sql = "SELECT * FROM $table_name WHERE ID = '$sessionID'";
  $qObj = $dbhandle -> prepare($sql) or &errorPage("Can't prepare.");
  $qObj -> execute() or &errorPage("Can't execute " . $qObj->errstr());
  my $rowhashref = $qObj->fetchrow_hashref();
  $qObj -> finish();

  if(! $rowhashref) { ### $rowhashref is an empty reference, which means no such id...
    &errorPage("No such session.");
  }
  my %hash = %$rowhashref;  ### get the actual hash containing the state record
  ### timeout test
  if(($time_out > 0) && ($hash{"last_modified"} < time - $time_out*24*60*60)){ 
    ### timed out...
    if($time_out_function) {
      &$time_out_function($time_out_message);
            exit;
    }
        else{
        &errorPage("Your session has timed out");
    }
  }
  ### touch the record
  $sql = "UPDATE $table_name SET last_modified = " . time . " WHERE ID = '$sessionID'";
  $qObj = $dbhandle -> prepare($sql) or &errorPage("Can't prepare.");
  $qObj -> execute() or &errorPage("Can't execute " . $qObj->errstr());
  $qObj -> finish();
  ### only need to return the actual state data
  delete $hash{"id"};
  delete $hash{"last_modified"};
  return %hash;           
}

#################################################################
sub get_long_id_db {
  my ($dbhandle, $table_name, $cache_limit, $file_life_span) = @_;

  ### count number of sessions
  my $sql = "SELECT id FROM $table_name";  
  my $qObj = $dbhandle -> prepare($sql) or &errorPage("Can't prepare.");
  $qObj -> execute() or &errorPage("Can't execute " . $qObj->errstr());
  $qObj -> fetchall_arrayref(); 

  if($qObj->rows() >= $cache_limit) {       ### Need to police table?
    my $expiredtime = int(time - $file_life_span*24*60*60); ### in seconds ###
    $qObj -> finish();

    ### police the table
    $sql = "DELETE FROM $table_name WHERE last_modified < $expiredtime";
    $qObj = $dbhandle -> prepare($sql) or &errorPage("Can't prepare.");;
    $qObj -> execute() or &errorPage("Can't execute " . $qObj->errstr()); 
    $qObj -> finish();

    ### count number of sessions again
    $sql = "SELECT id FROM $table_name";        
    $qObj = $dbhandle -> prepare($sql) or &errorPage("Can't prepare.");;
    $qObj -> execute() or &errorPage("Can't execute " . $qObj->errstr()); 
    $qObj -> fetchall_arrayref(); 

    if($qObj->rows() >= $cache_limit) { ### still over limit?
      # should generate e-mail message to warn administrator
      &errorPage("Site busy. Please try again later.");
    }
  }
  $qObj -> finish();

  my $id = &generate_random_string(32);
  my $currtime = time;

  ### create new state record
  $sql = "INSERT INTO $table_name (id, last_modified) values ('$id', $currtime)";
  $qObj = $dbhandle -> prepare($sql) or &errorPage("Can't prepare.");;
  $qObj -> execute() or &errorPage("Can't execute " . $qObj->errstr());

  return $id;
}

#################################################################
sub generate_random_string {
  my $n = $_[0];
  my $result = "";
  my @chars = (0..9, 'a'..'z', 'A'..'Z');
  my $which;
  for($i = 1 ; $i <= $n ; $i++) {
    $which=int rand 62;
   $result = $result . $chars[$which];
  }
  return $result;
}

#################################################################
sub errorPage {
 my $message = $_[0]; # the incoming parameter, store in localized variable
 print<<ALL;
 <html>
 <head>
  <title>Error encountered</title>
 </head>
 <body>
  <h1>Error Encountered</h1>
  <h3>$message</h3>
  Please try again, or report the problem to the webmaster.
 </body>
 </html>
ALL
 exit;
}
```

Comment: Enable the `strict`, `warnings`, and `diagnostics` pragmas.  Fix the things they complain about. Use a [debugger](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldebug.html) or well placed print statements to get an idea of what is happening in the parts of your code where you do the insert (is the data what you are expecting).  If you find a problem, work backwards until things look right, and then forwards until it looks wrong again.  The area between those two states is where your bug is.

Comment: If you *must* do CGI, please, [use the CGI module](http://perldoc.perl.org/CGI.html). This code is in a style from the early 1990s.

Answer (score 10):

It worries me terribly that you say this is "an assignment" as it implies that this is something that you are learning in school or college. I don't know how much of this code was given to you by your teacher or how much you have cobbled together from reading out of date information from the internet, but this is a style of writing web applications in Perl that is at least 15 years out of date.

- These days, we don't use CGI to write web applications in Perl. Modern Perl web applications are based on [PSGI and Plack](http://plackperl.org/).
- If you do insist on writing web applications using CGI, then the [CGI module](https://metacpan.org/pod/CGI) has been around since the mid-90s and will make your life easier. In particular, you should be using its `param()` function rather than your hand-written and buggy form-parsing code.
- It has been fifteen years since anyone recommended putting raw HTML into a a Perl program. You should use a [templating engine](https://metacpan.org/pod/Template) instead.

Outside of web-specific stuff, there is other stuff that you're doing which shows that you're learning from outdated sources.

- Ampersands on subroutine calls haven't been needed since Perl 5 was released in 1994 and they have a couple of "interesting" effects which mean the most people shouldn't use them most of the time.
- Most database access these days is written using [DBIx::Class](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBIx::Class) which is a wrapper on top of the raw DBI that you are using. Amongst other advantages it gives you, it will protect you from the SQL injection vulnerability that you have unwittingly included in your code.

And, finally, you would have found your problem yourself if you had not commented out the `use strict` in your code. That forces you to declare your variables and amongst the (many) errors it would have found would have been the fact that you are mistyping `%formHash` as `%fromHash`.

What you are learning here is so far from the Perl that will be useful to you in the workplace that this course is pretty close to being useless. If anyone at your college is interested in improving the quality of this course, I would be happy to help in any way I can.

Comment: I think you overstate some of the technologies here, especially, DBIx::Class. It's DBI that can protect you from SQL injection (but only if you use it wisely). What worries me is the hostile and rather unhelpful rage that gets misdirected to the person who doesn't know any better. It's not really the poster you're mad at.

Comment: @briandfoy: I agree that DBI can protect you from SQL injection, but you need to know how to use it correctly. But the default way to use DBIC protects you without without you having to think about it. Re-reading my answer, I don't really see any rage. I see me saying I'm worried about what they're learning and offering to help improve the course. I really hope the OP didn't think I was mad at him. That's far from the truth.

Answer (score 5):

The reason that the question is only thing which makes it into the database is that you're getting all the other values from `%fromHash`, which does not exist.  You put your data into `%formHash`, not `%fromHash`.

This is one of the (many!) types of problems which gets caught by the `strict` pragma.  `use strict` and `use warnings` should **absolutely not** be commented out.  **Ever.**  When you are learning Perl, they might seem a bit demanding, but they are actually your best friends.  Even as an experienced Perl programmer, I *always* have them enabled, except on very rare occasions in very small sections of code where I know the exact reason why they complain *and* the exact reason why that complaint is not applicable.

Also:

- Don't prefix your sub calls with `&`.  It's an obsolete Perl 4-ism.  In Perl 5, it has side-effects which you probably don't know about or want.
- If you're already using `CGI`, let it handle the form/parameter decoding for you (with the `param` method) instead of doing it by hand.  (In real production code, I'd say to use a proper web framework, such as Dancer or Mojolicious, instead of `CGI`, but I assume that the choice of `CGI` was dictated by your assignment.)
- Be aware that this code is vulnerable to SQL injection attacks. That's normally something I'd make a big deal about, but, since this is an introductory assignment for learning the language, I'll just mention it as something to look into later if you continue doing web programming.  You can see [Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com/) for more details about SQL injection, including examples of how to secure Perl code against such attacks.